# Using arrays for php quiz even though the array contains one thing

Tags: php, arrays

I have a quick question regarding php, lets say I had something like this:

```
<?php
$rightcolors = Array();
$leftcolors = Array();
$rightcolors[]="Yellow";
$leftcolors[]="Violet";
$rightcolors[]="Yellow Green";
$leftcolors[]="Red Violet";
$rightcolors[]="Green";
$leftcolors[]="Red";
$rightcolors[]="Blue Green";
$leftcolors[]="Red Orange";
$rightcolors[]="Blue";
$leftcolors[]="Orange";
$rightcolors[]="Blue Violet";
$leftcolors[]="Yellow Orange";
?>
```

But I want to not have array that contains different things, I rather want to label them separately like so:

```
<?php
$left="Green"
$leftcorrect="Yellow"
$blu="Blue"
$blucorrect="blu"
?>
```

Would it be appropriate to still use an array even though it only contains values? I am assuming this is not the correct way to do this and a lot of questions would involve a lot of different arrays which is not convenient. In that case would be the second list of little code with the different names be fine? The reason for this is before I was using arrays to allow the quiz to randomly ask one question, now I want to make a quiz that pulls very specific questions.

Comment: why not using key value arrays? Like $array['left'] = "green"; etc

Comment: @LioraHaydont ah ok so I just create the arrays as I go instead of creating separate arrays so I initialize and declare on one line correct?

Comment: Yes, you can chekc the doc here -> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php